# binding pop up button to relationship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa-bindings

I have 2 entities, Product and Manufacturer, they have a relationship in the data model

[image: datamodel]

I have a ProductsAC - array controller for product entities and ManufacturerAC - array controller for Manufacturers

I have a table view that lists all the products, and then I need to select the products manufacturer from a separate popup box. - I want to be able to select multiple products at once to 'allocate' the manufacturer.

I can bind the pop up to the manufacturerAC to get the data.

If I bind the selected object to the ProductAC.selection.manufacturer it will create the link until I close the app - then it crashes on load.

[image: bindings]

I have found many posts and blog entries on this but it seems to have changed over the years.

Can anyone help me bind this correctly?

Comment: Bind Selected Object to ProductAC, `selection`, `productManufacturer` (Typo?). Can you tell a bit more about "close the app - then it crashes on load"?

Comment: it's working! I was sure I did try the productManufacturer model key path before and it failed, I've closed it an opened it a few times now and it's working. Thank you so much.